# Рис (злак) может в специфическом (кулинарном) контексте иметь множественное число?

Tags: множественное-число, число

> 3 евро за порцию нежнейшего из рисов...

Это из описания особенностей блюд и цен конкретного ресторана.

Comment: ЭмГэшечка! Перепиши, плиз, коммент в ответ - автору аж в Рим пошлём!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В художественном произведении может.

Существительные, имеющие только формы ед. ч., называются существительными singularia tantum.

Отсутствие форм мн. ч. у существительных singularia tantum не означает невозможности образования у них форм со значением и внешними признаками мн. ч. В специальной литературе указывается, что слова singularia tantum могут быть определены как существительные с **потенциально полной парадигмой** (ед. и мн. ч.), но у них нормально употребляются только формы ед. ч.

Формы мн. ч. существительных singularia tantum отмечены в художественной литературе, особенно в поэзии: *Хватит с меня этих отдыхов! (Бунин); Колорит, развернутый приятелем, был отличный: в бархатах Тинторетто перекликались синевы Веронезе (К. Петров­Водкин); Друг! Дожди за моим окном, Беды и блажи на сердце (Цвет.); Он создал тысячи диковин И может не бояться стуж (Пастерн.); Земля! зеленая планета! Ничтожный шар в семье планет! Твое величье – имя это, Меж слав твоих – прекрасней нет! (Брюс.); сиплые низкие ревы пароходных гудков (Ю. Казак.).*

В тех случаях, когда возникает необходимость выразить отношение "единичность – множественность", у ряда существительных singularia tantum могут быть образованы формы мн. ч. Это следующие случаи.

1) У ряда вещественных и отвлеченных существительных выражается противопоставление "единичность – множественность"; при этом имеет место расхождение лексических значений форм ед. и мн. ч.

а) Вещественные существительные во мн. ч. обозначают виды, типы или сорта называемых веществ: вино – вина (форма мн. ч. обозначает сорта вин: красные вина, десертные вина и соотнесена в ед. ч. с соответствующим значением: красное вино, десертное вино, сухое вино); масло – масла (растительные, животные, технические), вода – воды (минеральные), крупа – крупы (манная, гречневая, овсяная), сталь – стали.

б) Существительные с отвлеченным значением во мн. ч. называют проявления различных качеств, свойств, эмоциональных состояний: возможность – возможности (средство, условие, необходимое для осуществления чего­н., возможное обстоятельство); аналогично: скорость – скорости, влажность – влажности, красота – красоты, глубина – глубины, радость – радости, печаль – печали, нежность – нежности. Ряд отвлеченных существительных во мн. ч. называет многоактное действие: гонка – гонки, сбор – сборы.

в) Некоторые собирательные существительные во мн. ч., и соответственно в ед. ч., называют устройства или конкретные множества: аппаратура – аппаратуры (лабораторий); клавиатура – клавиатуры (органа).

Рис - вещественное, нежнейший из рисов - самый нежный из всех сортов и блюд из риса. В разговорном стиле это нормально.

Comment: Люсенька, какая Вы умница!

Answer (score 1):

"3 евро за порцию нежнейшего из рисов..."

Думаю, так нельзя говорить (из рисов, из пшениц...). Корректно: порцию нежнейшего риса (о способе приготовления) или порцию нежнейшего из сортов риса (о сорте).